# Incorrect terminal height when left/right maximizing in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, window, 17.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and I have trouble with left/right maximizing the terminal window.
When I maximize the terminal window to a side of the screen it does not use the full screen height, and is sort of cut off on the bottom:

[image: Incorrectly scaled terminal]

When I open a new tab in the terminal, the height of the window extends beyond the screen height:

[image: Incorrectly scaled terminal #2]

This does not occur when maximizing the window fully, or with other applications.

The second issue makes it impossible to use the terminal with multiple tabs when left/right maximizing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is not necessarily a bug. Terminal applications usually ask the window manager to respect certain size criteria (multiple of cell size). In this case `GNOME Shell` respects this request. (Although it's indeed inconsistent that when you fully maximize, geometry hints are no longer respected and the "gap" will belong to `GNOME Terminal`.)

The second one looks like a bug, you should file it to `GNOME Shell`.

As a workaround, `GNOME Terminal` has a hidden config option to show the tab bar even if only a single tab is present. You can activate it with

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/tab-policy '"always"'
```

(and revert with `'"automatic"'` or `dconf reset ...`).

UPDATE:

`gnome-terminal` has just received a fix/workaround (not sure what to call it) for the second issue ([bugreport](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789356), [commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/commit/?id=2f33a36)). It'll appear in forthcoming version 3.28, and *might* get backported to 3.26.x too.

UPDATE2:

`GTK+` version 3.22.25 properly fixes both of these issues ([bugreport](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789357), [commit 1](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=465ef50), [commit 2](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=8ad40a4), [commit 3](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=72045a1) – I *think* it's the first commit that's really important here).